# code-behind inline inside event handler

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, code-behind

This xaml points to an event handler member function in the Completed event:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStory" Completed="myStoryCompleted" FillBehavior="Stop">
    <!-- storyboard things -->
</Storyboard>
```

As in my case I just want to play a simple sound when the Storyboard ends (don't know of a way to include sounds in a Storyboard!), I'd like to have "inline codebehind" in that Completed... if it's possible. Is it? Something like this:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStory" Completed="{mysound.Play();}" FillBehavior="Stop">
    <!-- storyboard things -->
</Storyboard>

<MediaElement x:Name="mysound" Source="/mysound.mp3" Volume="100" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems not possible after all. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just start thesound in code behind?

```
private void myStoryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.mysound.Play();
}
```

Comment: Of course (my current solution), but the xaml would be a lot more readable with inline code.

Comment: Jonny -- I don't believe you can do that in XAML. It is a declarative data-binding markup, right?